# Missing semicolon in JavaScript / JScript

Tags: javascript, hyperion, brio

I have the following code that I am writing inside BRIO (Hyperion Interactive Reporting Studio). The code is either in JavaScript or JScript, though I am not sure which as I am just learning the syntax and am not sure how they differ.

Anyway, I am getting syntax `Script(line number) missing; before statement` error on the following lines:

```
if (xYear == 2012 && yMonth == 10) {stopIt = "Yes"} else (yMonth == 12) {stopIt = "Yes"}
```

and

```
var myDate = New Date(xYear, yMonth, 1)
```

in the code below.

```
var xYear
var yMonth

for (j = 2009; j =  2012; j++)

{ 

    xYear = j

    if (xYear == 2009) {yMonth = 7} else {yMonth = 1}

    var StopIt = "No"

    Do 

    {
    var myDate = New Date(xYear, yMonth, 1)
    Alert (myDate)

    //var myQuery = ActiveDocument.Sections["qry_billing"]

    //myQuery.Limits["Accounting Year Month"].CustomValues.RemoveAll()
    //myQuery.Limits["Accounting Year Month"].CustomValues.Add(myDate)
    //myQuery.Limits["Accounting Year Month"].SelectedValues.Add(myDate)

    //myQuery.Process()

    //var Path = "W:\\Major Accounts\\Alliance Process\\AAA\\reference_files\\Results"
    //var File = "Results" + "_" + xYear + "_" +  yMonth+ " .txt"

    //ActiveDocument.Sections["Results"].Export(Path + "\\" + File,bqExportFormatText,true)

    yMonth = yMonth + 1

    if (xYear == 2012 && yMonth == 10) {stopIt = "Yes"} else if (yMonth == 12) {stopIt = "Yes"}
    }

    While (stopIt != "Yes")

}
```

Can someone please help me fix this issue, as I don't understand why it's asking me for the `;`, as I thought it wasn't even needed in BRIO document scripts.

Comment: Assuming this doesn't have anything to do with `[java]`.

Comment: shouldnt it be else if (yMonth == 12) {..... ?

Comment: JScript and JavaScript are both implementations of **ECMAScript**. You can assume they are the same.

Comment: I don't know much about JS but should `else (yMonth == 12)` be `else if (yMonth == 12)` ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey -> thanks. I am still a bit confused with java vs JScript vs JavaScript! And yes, I changed the `else` to `else if`, but that does not affect my other syntax error.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen. Are semicolons mandatory in JScript?

Comment: `Do`, `While`, `Alert` and `New` should be `do`, `while` etc. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Teemu -> That fixed it along, with gdoron's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
else (yMonth == 12)
```

Should be:

```
else if (yMonth == 12)
```

And when you indent the code properly, it's easy to notice this error:

```
if (xYear == 2012 && yMonth == 10) {
    stopIt = "Yes"
} 
else (yMonth == 12) { // shoule be: else if (yMonth == 12) {
    stopIt = "Yes"
}
```

Notes: javascript is **case sensitive** which means

- `Do` isn't `do`
- so as for `alert` instead of `Alert`
- `new` instead of `New`

But semicolons are not mandatory, you can use them or use not, as you wish.

**Update:**

From looking at the full code you posted, man, it has lots of weird things.

```
for (j = 2009; j =  2012; j++)
```

Should be something like:

```
for (var j = 2009; j <= 2012; j++)
...
```

You define a variable:

```
var StopIt = "No"
```

But use `stopIt` instead:

```
stopIt = "Yes"
```

You should take a javascript course\tutorial, it's not that difficult to learn, but your code in it's current state is totally broken!

Comment: thanks for this catch, however, it doesn't solve my posted problem.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman. Then you have other errors in your code. What is the new error you're getting?

Comment: semicolon after stopIt = "Yes"

Comment: That fixed the `If Then Else If` statement! Thanks. @Teemu's comment fixed the other line. It was a case sensitivity thing.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, Tips from me: 1) Use `JSlint`. 2) write small amount of code and check if it works, then continue to the next small amount test it again... until you finish.

Comment: Thanks for the edits / updates and tips gdoron. Very appreciative. I am trying something on the fly at the moment, these lessons are appreciated for my future learning.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar, You should know that semicolons are not mandatory in javascript. some loves it some hates it, some, like me, don't give a damn. :)

Comment: @gdoron the OP is using Brio / Hyperion BI / Oracle EPM, which uses its own proprietary version of JavaScript.  A lot of what you're saying is wrong because of that.  For instance, the `alert()` function allows Hyperion to use the JavaScript version, but `Alert()` calls the Hyperion-specific version which takes different parameters.  Another example (which he probably isn't using correctly anyway) is that if a variable is not declared with `var` is a way to create a global variable for the application (though it's proper form to declare those in the onStartup() Document script).

Answer (score 0):

For clarity sake, the answer to my question was two-fold, based on gdoron's very helpful and informative answer and Teemu's comment under my original post. To sum up the answer I've answered my own question below:

The error in this statement

```
if (xYear == 2012 && yMonth == 10) {stopIt = "Yes"} else (yMonth == 12) {stopIt = "Yes"}
```

is that is was missing `if` after the `else`

So it should look like this:

```
if (xYear == 2012 && yMonth == 10) {
    stopIt = "Yes"
}
else if (yMonth == 12) {
    stopIt = "Yes"
}
```

The error in this statement

```
var myDate = New Date(xYear, yMonth, 1)
```

was that `New` should not have been capitailized. So it should be written as:

```
var myDate = new Date(xYear, yMonth, 1)
```

Comment: But there were many more... :) there was a lot of case mistakes.

Comment: ugh! I see that now. I am going through snippet by snippet as you said :)